# uboot a hello world kernel

Tags: qemu, bootloader, u-boot

For a Hello world uboot project I am using [this](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/u-boot-for-arm-on-qemu) tutorial.

I have used GNU ARM toolchain
Downloaded Uboot source : u-boot-2017.09

Compiled it

```
make vexpress_ca9x4_defconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=../gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-

make all ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=../gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-
```

And the hello world project looks like

**test.c**

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x101f1000;
void print_uart0(const char *s) {
    while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
        *UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
        s++; /* Next char */
    }
}
void c_entry() {
    print_uart0("Hello world!\n");
}
```

**startup.s**

```
.global _Reset
_Reset:
 LDR sp, =stack_top
 BL c_entry
 B .
```

**test.ld**

```
ENTRY(_Reset)
SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x100000; /*initial address*/
 .startup . : { startup.o(.text) }
 .text : { *(.text) }
 .data : { *(.data) }
 .bss : { *(.bss COMMON) }
 . = ALIGN(8);
 . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB of stack memory */
 stack_top = .;
}
```

**And the compilation**

```
../gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s test.c -o test.o

../gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=arm926ej-s startup.s -o startup.o

../gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld -T test.ld -Map=test.map test.o startup.o -o test.elf

../gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin
```

**Create Image :**

```
mkimage -A arm -C none -O linux -T kernel -d test.bin -a 0x00100000 -e 0x00100000 test.uimg
```

**Output :**

```
Image Name:   
Created:      Mon Oct 23 20:58:01 2017
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    146 Bytes = 0.14 kB = 0.00 MB
Load Address: 00100000
Entry Point:  00100000
```

**Create a single binary :**

```
cat ../u-boot-2017.09/u-boot test.uimg > flash.bin
```

**Calculated uboot binary size**

```
printf "bootm 0x%X\n" $(expr $(stat -c%s u-boot.bin) + 65536)
bootm 0x218F20
```

**Then run :**

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -kernel flash.bin -m 128M -nographic
```

Interrupted it and then run `bootm 0x218F20`
But it says

```
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Either try go command with same built image (go 0x218F20) Or to use bootm 
refer [1] (5.12.3. Processor cache considerations), the mkimage command seems to be wrong.

[1] https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootStandalone